# vertical scroll view for dynamically created buttons

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview

I am having a problems with adding scroll view in my dynamically created buttons.here is my xml code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_border"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="243dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/hinttextitem" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
        android:onClick="newonClick"
        android:text="click" />
  </LinearLayout>


     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/dynamic"
        android:background="@drawable/dynamic_border"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
      </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

here is my java code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void newonClick(View V){
    LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear1);
    LinearLayout dynamiclayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.dynamic);
    dynamiclayout.removeAllViews();
    EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); 
    int x=Integer.valueOf(edittext.getText().toString());
    for(int i=1;i<=x;i++)
    {
      Button addButton =new Button(this);
      addButton.setText("Button"+i);
      addButton.setId(i);
      dynamiclayout.addView(addButton);
      addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                  "button is clicked"+v.getId(), 8000).show();
         }
      });
    }
```

if am adding scroll view in dynamic layout, it will disappear.so how can i add vertical scroll view only for dynamically created buttons.can anyone solve my problem?

Comment: where did you creating scrollview?

Comment: And you didn't call your newonClick(View v) method from your oncreate :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:  place scroll view for LinearLayout only.

```
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dynamic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dynamic_border"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: thanks all..its working for me..one more help i needed that how can i add gridview in dynamic created buttons here.now am getting the button as vertical , i want to show it as grid..

Comment: take a grid view instead of LinearLayout and maintain one adaptor for grid functionality, your dynamic button information is pass to adaplter.

Comment: @balaji.am a beginer in android, can u post that how to pass the dynamic button info in to adapter..

Comment: @ammu here is the simple example for gridview and custom adapter functionality, try this   http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/android-custom-grid-view-example-with-image-and-text.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to use,
In XML,

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear1" 
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1">

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dynamic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

In Java:

```
this.scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
this.linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dynamic);
this.linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
Button[] btn = new Button[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    btn[i] = new Button(this);
    btn[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    btn[i].setText("This is the button" + i);
   this.linearLayout.addView(btn[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dynamic"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

please replace this code: